# Calculate logarithm in python

Tags: python

I am wondering why the result of `log base 10 (1.5)` in python = 0.405465108108 while the real answer = 0.176091259.

This is the code that I wrote:

```
import math
print math.log(1.5)
```

Can someone tell how to solve this issue?

Comment: Because like in most languages, `log` is logarithm in base e (natural logarithm), not base 10. If you want log in base 10, use `log10`.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/log-functions-python/

Answer (score 53, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.log):

> With one argument, return the natural logarithm of *x* (to base *e*).
>
> With two arguments, return the logarithm of *x* to the given *base*, calculated as `log(x)/log(base)`.

But the log<sub>10</sub> is made available as `math.log10()`, which does not resort to log division if possible.

Comment: You are amazing!

Answer (score 21):

If you use log without base it uses `e`.

From the comment

> Return the logarithm of x to the given base.
>   If the base not specified, returns the natural logarithm (base e) of x.

Therefor you have to use:

```
import math
print( math.log(1.5, 10))
```

Comment: `math.log(x, n)` is useful when you have custom base, but if you want logarithm base 2 or 10, use `math.log2` or `math.log10`.

Comment: You are right, using `log10` directly has a better readability and is less prone to errors

Comment: math.log2(x) doesn't exist until Python 3.3. For Python 2 you have to use math.log(x, 2).

Answer (score 14):

```
math.log10(1.5)
```

Use the log10 function in the math module.

Answer (score 11):

The [`math.log`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.log) function is to the base `e`, i.e. natural logarithm. If you want to the base 10 use [`math.log10`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.log10).