# Calculating Log base c in python3

Tags: python-3.x, logging

Is there a way to calculate log base c in python?
c is a variable and may change due to some dependencies.

I am new to programming and also python3.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate logarithm in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33754670/calculate-logarithm-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is already a built in function in the math module in python that does this.

```py
from math import log

def logOc(c, num):
    return log(num,c)

print(log(3,3**24))
```

[You can read more about log and the python math module here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/math.html#math.log)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can simply use math's function log():

```
import math
c = 100
val = math.log(10000,c) #Where the first value is the number and the second the base.
print(val)
```

Example:

```
print(val)
2.0
```

Comment: I'm glad both answers did, feel free to accept either of them to mark your question as answered.